# Run Macro Dropdown List Excel

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I wrote this Macro out to copy and paste info from a previous sheet to the active sheet. I want to make this into a dropdown list but when using data validation, the macro doesn't run when it is picked. Attached is my code and I am wondering should I make a list box or should I stick with data validation? I know there's a way to make a macro run once clicked in a click box

```
Sub WorkDay1()
ActiveSheet.Range("A6:H44").Value = Worksheets("Route Sheet - Manhattan 1").Range("A6:H44").Value

End Sub
Sub WorkDay2()

ActiveSheet.Range("A6:H44").Value = Worksheets("2").Range("A6:H44").Value
End Sub


Sub WorkDay3()
ActiveSheet.Range("A6:H44").Value = Worksheets("3").Range("A6:H44").Value
End Sub

Sub WorkDay4()
ActiveSheet.Range("A6:H44").Value = Worksheets("4").Range("A6:H44").Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dropdown list is in cell A1.

Paste this code into the worksheets code module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case "WorkDay1"
                WorkDay1
            Case "WorkDay2"
                WorkDay2
            Case "WorkDay3"
                WorkDay3
            Case "WorkDay4"
                WorkDay4
        End Select
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

In the VBA Project explore double click the Sheet that you wish to run the macro on.  This will open up the code module for that sheet.  Then paste the code into that module.

[image]

Adding this colud will update the values when you select the worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Select Case Range("A1")
        Case "WorkDay1"
            WorkDay1
        Case "WorkDay2"
            WorkDay2
        Case "WorkDay3"
            WorkDay3
        Case "WorkDay4"
            WorkDay4
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, what do I do about the worksheet selection it is on? I entered it but it still is not performing the action. I edited the cell to proper cell I was in J7 but do I need to specify which worksheet im running it on? Pretty much adding it to active sheet

Comment: did you see my comment?

Comment: Thank you! It works like that - quick q tho, it doesn't auto run after it's clicked on the list. I would have to go back to the list and reclick it for it to fill in the form - any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, that did not do anything that second part. It still is requiring a final click to run the macro after you select it from the list

Comment: The alternative is to use a combobox.

Comment: How does a combobox work in relation to a drop down type of system? Will it be similarly written?

Comment: Yes they are very simular.   [Check out this Combo Box tutorial](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/combo-box.html)